# Need to change my date format

Tags: php

How can I change the format of my date from 2016-10-05 to 10/05/2016 in php

```
$date= $row['date'];
```

So when the row echos out it'll all be the new format

Comment: Can you show the code for the calendar, it's most likely javascript.

Comment: Use `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) to create an object (from the current format), allowing you to reformat the output.

```
$date = "2016-10-05";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-m', $date);
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

https://repl.it/DqvO